# Repeating "I" in an enumeration of attributes

Tags: verbs, pronouns, conjunction-reduction

Since I like staying up until late at night, waking up late, and generally [I] am more of a nocturnal type of person…

Is the I in the square brackets necessary, or can it be omitted? Personally, I feel like it sounds better when left out, but some people told me otherwise. Please clear up the confusion, thanks!

Comment: Ellipsis of the second "I" is just fine, but *I like X,Y, and Z* leads the reader expect a third thing you like after the *and*. You need to forestall this interpretation by writing *I like X and Y, and generally am Z*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is wrong on a more basic level. After the 'since', relevant 'things I like' are listed, but the list requires A, B & C not A, B & - oops:

Since I like (staying up until late at night), (waking up late), and *(generally [I] am more of a nocturnal type of person…

With

Since I like staying up until late at night and waking up late, and generally [I] am more of a nocturnal type of person,

we now have the structure Since I (D + D') and (E):

Since I (like staying up until late at night and waking up late), and ({generally} [I] am more of a nocturnal type of person),

so the second I is incorrect.

Semantically, as E is a restatement of D, *and* would be better replaced by *in fact*.

Comment: Or, as StoneyB said, you could replace the comma after *night* with 'and'.

Answer (score 3):

In speech, in a conversation -- in **real** language, where these problems mostly don't arise, or are corrected on the spot when they do -- you would automatically contract ***I am*** to ***I'm***, which is not really the same word as ***I*** (doesn't rhyme, includes a verb, etc), and therefore doesn't trigger those mental "good manner" detectors that make repetition of ***I*** sound, um, ... less than "better" to many of us.

Then you say something about somebody else, or you ask a question and get an answer and get the floor back. Either way, you clear the pronoun buffer. **Then** you can say ***I*** again.

**Moral**: Written lists of your personal attributes are probably best not submitted for publication.